# Elasticsearch boost with Wildcardsearch on _all

Tags: boost, indexing, elasticsearch

Im trying to search documents with wildcard and _all. But It does not seem like it's possible to get boosted result with wildcard on _all ?

MappingRequest:

```
"theboostingclass": {
    "properties": {
      "Important": {
        "boost": 2.0,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "LessImportant": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Garbage": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indexing:

```
{
    "index" : 
    {
        "_index":"boosting",
        "_type":"theboostingclass"
    } 
} 
    {
        "Important":"bomb",
        "LessImportant":"kruka",
        "Garbage":"kalkon"
    }
{ 
    "index" :  
    {
        "_index":"boosting",
        "_type":"theboostingclass"
    }
}
{
    "Important":"kalkon",
    "LessImportant":"bomb",
    "Garbage":"bomber"
}
{ 
    "index" :  
    {
        "_index":"boosting",
        "_type":"theboostingclass"
    } 
}
{
    "Important":"kruka",
    "LessImportant":"bomber",
    "Garbage":"bomb"
}
```

Query

```
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "_all": {
        "value": "*bomb*"
      }
    }
  }
```

The result returs all hits with a Score of 1 and a seemingly random order. Which is not really what Im after. I want the hit on "Important"field to yield a higher score.

If I do a wildcard search on all 3 fields the scoring seems correct. However I want to use it on _all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please see documentation here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html.  Note that the reason it works with a constant scoring by default is for performance.

I believe you need to modify your query as follows:

```
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "_all": {
        "value": "*bomb*",
        "rewrite": "scoring_boolean"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow thank you. At least now I get scoring. Unfortunately I cant get him to score the "important" field higher. I want one hit on that single field to score higher than hits on the other fields. (Ive tried to boost it up and lower the others) I must be missing something.. ?

edit:I tried to add two new items. One with exact matching field important and one with the exact matching field on garbage. Both "bomb". The one on important field returned less score than the other.. even if its just by little. How is it even possible?

Comment: I'm guessing, but it looks like there are two matches for the other two and only one for the first.  "bomber" is also a match.  Exact matching won't matter at all in this query.  If you want to boost exact matches you would have to add another parameter to your query with a boost.

Comment: Yes it seems like it. But that is what Im trying to fix with boost. So even if there is two field matching I want a match on the "important" field to score higher.